# Creating string with libxml2 (c++)

Tags: c++, libxml2

My problem is that I want to create xml tree and get a simple string object (or even char*).
And I can't save xml to file.

So in the input I have xmlDocPtr with complete xml tree and want to get string containing xml but without using files.

Thx for attention.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [xmlDocDumpMemory](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlDocDumpMemory) or any of its cousins. Usage:

```
void xml_to_string(xmlDocPtr doc, std::string &out)
{
    xmlChar *s;
    int size;
    xmlDocDumpMemory(doc, &s, &size);
    if (s == NULL)
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    try {
        out = (char *)s;
    } catch (...) {
        xmlFree(s);
        throw;
    }
    xmlFree(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something I wrote while ago. Hope it helps....

```
xmlDocPtr pDoc = ... // your xml docuemnt

xmlCharPtr psOutput;
int iSize;
xmlDocDumpFormatMemoryEnc(pDoc, &psOutput, &iSize, "UTF-8", 1);

// psOutput should point to the string.

// Don't forget to free the memory.
xmlFree(psOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use xmlDocDumpMemory() be careful. Call xmlCleanupParser() at the very end, after using xmlDocDumpMemory(). It seems like xmlDocDumpMemory() uses it internaly.

Answer (score -1):

I couldnt get exactly what you want but after changing the node value you can save it [easily](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlDocDump) with xmlDocDump.

Comment: The OP says he does *not* want to save the XML to a file.

Comment: ups.. i think i couldnt get the problem well.